# How to make buttons look something like a list

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I have buttons which look like this:[image]

I want to make them look like this :
[image]

My `background.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/solid" />        
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape" />
</layer-list>
```

`solid.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ababab" />   
</shape>
```

And the `shape.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" /> 
    <stroke android:width="3dp" color="#ff000000" /> 
    <corners android:radius="15dp" /> 
    <padding 
        android:left="10dp" 
        android:top="10dp" 
        android:right="10dp" 
        android:bottom="10dp" /> 
</shape>
```

How can I get the desired appearance of the buttons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Top shape:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="3dp"
        android:top="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffffff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#ff000000" />
</shape>
```

Middle shape:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <padding
        android:left="3dp"
        android:top="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffffff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#ff000000" />
</shape>
```

Bottom shape:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="3dp"
        android:top="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffffff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#ff000000" />
</shape>
```

Example:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/top"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Top" />
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/middle"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:text="Middle" />
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/bottom"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
    android:text="Bottom" />
```

Look at `android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"` - you need it to overlap border of top button with border of bottom button

Result (the graphic is not so good, sry):
[image]

After some tweaking you'll have a shape as you expect.

My tweaking: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with bitmaps or images.  You'd need three images.  One for the top button, one for the middle buttons, and one for the bottom button.  Then just set the buttons to their appropriate background images.

Answer (score 0):

I take a different approach to do this.

Usually I create a rounded corner background with will correspond to the background of the whole set of buttons. (Usually I have a linear layout wrapping them.) Then, there is a separator between each button.

That should do what you want in a simple way.